# Add Table To Markdown File Via Windows Command Line

Tags: windows, command-line

I'm trying to append a table in a markdown file via command line. First, I make a new directory, `cd` into the directory, and then create an MD file, and then add a table. I'm getting an error with this command that says: `| was unexpected at this time.`. Anyone know how to insert a table into an MD file via command line?

```
mkdir Project_Name & cd Project_Name & echo # Notes > notes.md & echo |Name|Position|email|phone|website 1|website 2|website 3|
|---|---|---|---|---|---|---| >> notes.md
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PIPE `|` symbol has other functions within command line

So you would need to use quotes to place those character into your file

`echo "|Name|Position|email|phone|website 1|website 2|website 3| |---|---|---|---|---|---|---|"`

Use of the escape character to use certain characters will not put the quotes into your file.

`echo ^|Name^|Position^|email^|phone^|website 1^|website 2^|website 3^| >>notes.md & echo ^|---^|---^|---^|---^|---^|---^|---^| >>notes.md`

Comment: hmm, but with that I just get a file that has `"|Name|Position|email|phone|website 1|website 2|website 3||---|---|---|---|---|---|---|"` instead of a table.

Comment: Added an alternative method that should be correct markdown format for your file.